# How make DBLookupcombobox has a Windows 7 Look with RAD 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm using RAD 2010 on windows 7 and all visual components looks normal (Edit, DBCombobox, for example) but the dblookupcombobox has the same border theme from Windows XP. I can't find how make it's looks like the other components. Anyone has any idea of how i can make this?
Thanks PS: Sorry by the bad english.

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered that the reason for this behavior it that `TDBLookupComboBox` is a descendant of `TCustomControl`. Most similar controls are descendants of `TCustomEdit`, `TCustomComboBox` or `TCustomListBox`, which all call `TWinControl.CreateSubClass` to utilize a preregistered [System Window Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#system) of `EDIT`, `COMBOBOX`, and `LISTBOX`, respectively.

Since neither `TDBLookupComboBox` nor any of its ancestors do this, it just gets a plain border drawn due to the `WS_BORDER` flag in its `Params.Style`.

I'm going to assume there is a valid reason that `TDBLookupComboBox` does not call `CreateSubClass` to get a Windows `COMBOBOX`, but I'm not sure why. Maybe a future version of the `VCL` will utilize this.